# ngspice - Measure param

Tags: spice, ngspice

I'm trying to post-process a value computed by a `measure` statement in ngspice (rev 26) as described in the manual:

```
.measure tran osct TRIG v(out) VAL=1.65 RISE=10 TARG v(out) VAL=1.65 RISE=11
.measure tran oscf param='1/osct'
```

`osct` gets measured correctly but the second one fails with:

```
Error: measure 'oscf'
no such function as 'param=1/osct'
meas tran oscf param=1/osct failed!
```

Is this a bug, syntax change, or am I simply doing this wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This is a syntax error. A good way to debug syntax errors is change the input and get it to work, then find out what doesn't work. Throw in a + instead of a / and see if that works. Depending on the spice package, using maths in statements may or may not work. BTW Ltspice would handle this.

Answer (score 0):

Read the manual, 15.4.10 par('expression'). 
The .meas statement for PAR='xx' requires xx to be either a .param or an expression containing nothing but constants and/or .params. In your '1/osct', osct is a value computed during the last simulation and this is explicitly forbidden.

Using the MEAS syntax (no dot) in a .control section is also possible and superior in many cases.